# Angular reactive forms - Best practise for reusable input that transforms value

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components, angular-forms, angular-pipe

I'm working on an application that will have about 150 forms. Almost all these forms need to include an input field that transforms a numeric value to a formatted value with commas every 3 digits. (And a lot more similar reusable inputs, but I took this one as a simple example)

Because this behaviour will be repeated so often I want to make this input reusable. I was wondering what would be the best way to implement this.

I have researched using Directives, Pipes and nested components using CVA, however I still don't know what the best way to tackle the problem is. I'm skewing towards nested components, but would that be overkill when the component would be a form with a single input.

I expect the result to be easily reusable on input/ the input itself being reusable. Either with a single keyword in the element (Pipes/Directives) or with a selector (component).

Comment: You can always create a custom component with all the logic needed for the formatting, but I will probably go with the directive.

Comment: Directive would be the right choice here.